# How to use Regular expression to surround all number with a $ sign? Sublime Text 3

Tags: python-3.x, latex, sublimetext3

I have a table in latex, I am using sublime text. The question is simple, I have numbers say 
Input:

```
3.3 & 42.32 & 123
```

Is there a way using regular expression to replace numbers with the same numbers in addition to $ sign wrap such that the 
Output:

```
$3.3$ & $42.32$ & $123$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer. However, I honestly advise everyone who does not know Regular expression to watch the first four series

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9HbsUSWilw

The answer to my question is that I am using regular expression in Sublime text 3 editor. Therefore, the answer is to put in the find (ctr+F)

```
Find: (\d+\.\d*)
Replace with: \$$1\$ (after pressing on the regler expression key in sublime text 3)
```